# Store array list in variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to store the array list in a variable but have no clue how to solve it.

The xpath will return a list of items, and it is displayed in console just fine. My issue is that I have no idea how I could store it in a variable to use the list later.

If I try to use "arrayList" it will only return the last item from the array, but in console it displays all items.

Any ideas?

```js
var iterator = document.evaluate('xpathgoeshere', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

  while (thisNode) {
    var arrayList = (thisNode.textContent);
    var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
      console.log(arrayList);
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  dump('Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e);
}
```

Comment: What is `arrayEpisodes`, and why are you not using the index `arrayList[i]` in your loop?

Comment: @StevenSpungin Sorry, forgot to update the name, it is arrayList as well. If I use arrayList[i] it returns the same result for me.

Do you know why my variable only returns the last result?

Comment: `textContent` is a string, so not sure why you are iterating it.  Also, try to put `var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();` at the end of the while.  If you want to store the items, create an array and stash them.   I will add a snippet to solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first you should update `thisNode` after your loop, becaus `arrayList` is facing `thisNode`.

The next issue could be, that you're setting `iterator.iterateNext();` to a new `var thisNode` inside your while-loop, instead of updating your `var thisNode` inside your try-block. (because of the `var` infront of it)

Try this: :)

```
var iterator = document.evaluate('xpathgoeshere', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

  while (thisNode) {
    var arrayList = thisNode.textContent;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
      console.log(arrayList[i]);
    }    
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  }
} catch (e) {
  dump('Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e);
}
```

As Steven mentioned, `thisNode.textContent` is a string. I dont know how your sting looks like, but maybe you have to `split()` it first, or if its a JSONstring you have to use `JSON.parse()`, to get your Array.

---

But, if your `thisNode.textContext`s should be the items of your Array, try this:

```
var iterator = document.evaluate('xpathgoeshere', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  var arrayList = [];

  while (thisNode) {
    arrayList.push(thisNode.textContent); 
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  }

  console.log(arrayList);

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    console.log(arrayList[i]);
  }   
} catch (e) {
  dump('Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e);
}
```

Comment: Yes the second one is correct, the items are from thisNode.textContext. And thank you so much J. Sadi, works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add your nodes to an array.

```js
var iterator = document.evaluate('//div', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

const items = []

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  while (thisNode) {
    items.push(thisNode)
    var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  }
} catch (e) {
  dump('Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e);
}

console.log(items);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```